# How to add number of dictionaries to one list of new json file and remove last comma from json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, file, dictionary

I have large number of dictionaries so i created new Json file with that dictionaries, but the dictionaries are not adding in to one list and while creating new json file it won't remove the last comma

Here i'm writing how my data looks like, Can anyone suggest better way

Thanks in Advance help would be appropriate!!!

json_dict = {}
for li in jsonli:
json_dict.update(li)

`with open(r"D:\Users\laki.aya\Desktop\Invalidemail\stc.json", 'a+') as fout: fout.write(json.dumps(json_dict, indent = 4,default=str)) fout.write(',\n') fout.close()`

I'm getting output like this below:

OUTPUT:

> {
> "email": "zxxxccxxcc@gmail.com",
> "properties": [
> {
> "property": "XlinkUserID",
> "value": 5123456
> },
> {
> "property": "register_time",
> "value": "2022-12-01"
> },
> {
> "property": "linked_alexa",
> "value": 0
> },
> {
> "property": "linked_googlehome",
> "value": 0
> },
> {
> "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
> "value": 1
> }
> ]
> },
> {
> "email": "zyyyyyyuser@gmail.com",
> "properties": [
> {
> "property": "XlinkUserID",
> "value": 188882272
> },
> {
> "property": "register_time",
> "value": "2022-09-16"
> },
> {
> "property": "linked_alexa",
> "value": 1
> },
> {
> "property": "linked_googlehome",
> "value": 0
> },
> {
> "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
> "value": 1
> }
> ]
> },
> {
> "email": "z3@gmail.com",
> "properties": [
> {
> "property": "XlinkUserID",
> "value": 100000708
> },
> {
> "property": "register_time",
> "value": "2022-11-30"
> },
> {
> "property": "linked_alexa",
> "value": 0
> },
> {
> "property": "linked_googlehome",
> "value": 0
> },
> {
> "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
> "value": 1
> }
> ]
> },

```
I'm expecting data should in one list and remove the last comma


**Expected**

`[
  {
    "email": "zxxxccxxcc@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 5123456
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-12-01"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "email": "zyyyyyyuser@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 188882272
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-09-16"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
},
{
    "email": "z3@gmail.com",
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "XlinkUserID",
            "value": 100000708
        },
        {
            "property": "register_time",
            "value": "2022-11-30"
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_alexa",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "linked_googlehome",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
}
]



`
Can any suggest where I'm missing and how can I proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `jsonlines` may help you:
https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

If you are interested in only creating one list in the output file you can do this in the loop creating the file itself:

```
import json

with open(r"D:\Users\laki.aya\Desktop\Invalidemail\stc.json", 'wt') as fout:
    fout.write("[\n")
    is_empty = True
    for li in in jsonli:
        if not is_empty:
            fout.write(',\n')
        fout.write(json.dumps(li, indent = 4,default=str))
        is_empty = False
    fout.write("]\n")
    # close not neccessary, due to context manager
```

If you want to let the file continuously grow, a performant way is to use jsonlines, since new data is only appended to the text file:

```
import json, jsonlines

jsonli = [{"email": "zxxxccxxcc@gmail.com",
         "properties": [ 
            { "property": "XlinkUserID", "value": 5123456 }, 
            { "property": "register_time", "value": "2022-12-01" }
            ]
         }] * 3

with jsonlines.open(r"output.jsonl", 'a') as writer:
    for li in jsonli:
        writer.write(li)
    # close not neccessary, due to context manager

with jsonlines.open(r"output.jsonl", "r") as reader:
    for item in reader.iter():
        assert(isinstance(item, dict))
        print(json.dumps(item))
```

(see also: https://dbconvert.com/blog/json-lines-data-stream/)

---

A little "hackish" solution:

```py
import json
from pprint import PrettyPrinter
from os import SEEK_END


item_1 = {
    "email": "zxxxccxxcc@gmail.com", "properties": [
        {"property": "XlinkUserID", "value": 5123456},
        {"property": "register_time", "value": "2022-12-01"},
        {"property": "linked_alexa", "value": 0},
        {"property": "linked_googlehome", "value": 0},
        {"property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_", "value": 1},
        {"property": "umlauts", "value": "äüö"}]
}


item_2 = {
    "email": "zyyyyyyuser@gmail.com", "properties": [
        {"property": "XlinkUserID", "value": 188882272},
        {"property": "register_time", "value": "2022-09-16"},
        {"property": "linked_alexa", "value": 1},
        {"property": "linked_googlehome", "value": 0},
        {"property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_", "value": 1},
        {"property": "umlauts", "value": "éîß"}]
}


item_3 = {
    "email": "z3@gmail.com", "properties": [
        {"property": "XlinkUserID", "value": 100000708},
        {"property": "register_time", "value": "2022-11-30"},
        {"property": "linked_alexa", "value": 0},
        {"property": "linked_googlehome", "value": 0},
        {"property": "n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_", "value": 1},
        {"property": "umlauts", "value": "ÄÜÖ"}]
}


def append_dict_to_json_file(filename: str, item: dict, *, reset: bool = False):
    with open(filename, "r+b") as f:
        if reset:
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate()
            f.write(b"[")
        else:
            f.seek(-1, SEEK_END)  # remove "]" at end of file
            f.write(b",")
        f.write(json.dumps(item, indent=None, separators=(",", ":"), ensure_ascii=True).encode("ascii"))
        f.write(b"]")


append_dict_to_json_file("dict_example.json", item_1, reset=True)
append_dict_to_json_file("dict_example.json", item_2)
append_dict_to_json_file("dict_example.json", item_3)

with open("dict_example.json", "r") as f:
    test = json.load(f)
print("Type: %s" % (type(test),))
print("Length: %d" % (len(test),))
print("Content: ...")
pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(test)
```

Output:

```
Type: <class 'list'>
Length: 3
Content: ...
[   {   'email': 'zxxxccxxcc@gmail.com',
        'properties': [   {'property': 'XlinkUserID', 'value': 5123456},
                          {'property': 'register_time', 'value': '2022-12-01'},
                          {'property': 'linked_alexa', 'value': 0},
                          {'property': 'linked_googlehome', 'value': 0},
                          {   'property': 'n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_',
                              'value': 1},
                          {'property': 'umlauts', 'value': 'äüö'}]},
    {   'email': 'zyyyyyyuser@gmail.com',
        'properties': [   {'property': 'XlinkUserID', 'value': 188882272},
                          {'property': 'register_time', 'value': '2022-09-16'},
                          {'property': 'linked_alexa', 'value': 1},
                          {'property': 'linked_googlehome', 'value': 0},
                          {   'property': 'n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_',
                              'value': 1},
                          {'property': 'umlauts', 'value': 'éîß'}]},
    {   'email': 'z3@gmail.com',
        'properties': [   {'property': 'XlinkUserID', 'value': 100000708},
                          {'property': 'register_time', 'value': '2022-11-30'},
                          {'property': 'linked_alexa', 'value': 0},
                          {'property': 'linked_googlehome', 'value': 0},
                          {   'property': 'n0x89_direct_connect_full_color_bulb__a19_',
                              'value': 1},
                          {'property': 'umlauts', 'value': 'ÄÜÖ'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for you're response the above method is not much useful and we are dealing with very large file where 8m lines of json file

Comment: If performance is an important point, then look at https://pypi.org/project/pylines/ as well.

Comment: can you suggest in above code where should i change

Comment: Updated example

Comment: the data is adding only we use with open(r"D:\Users\lakshmi.vijaya\Desktop\Invalidemail\stc.json", 'a+')
in the file it is creating list of list, [{[....]}] [{[....]}] like this data is creating in json file and in between it not adding comma, also, I'm trying data should be in one list and need to  remove last comma, if possible can you see once above requirement please

Comment: Hi @Andreas, can you  check above comment

Comment: Do you have a simple example dataset to share to reproduce the issues?

Comment: I edited my example in above can you check once due to some mail issues i'm unable to logon stackoverflow, so late replied